# Using TI Nspire to store variables and carry out a defined equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I am trying to store three variables $$A=2.42528, B=1.41421, c= 1.61106$$ that I can change at anytime and then calculate the following equation:

$$\theta_4=2\left[{tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-B\pm\sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}\right)}\right]$$

I have used $ctrl + var$ to store $a$, $b$ and $c$ (note I couldn't store them in capitals like I needed). I then went to $menu→$ $Actions→$ $Define$ and typed:

$$Define \space\theta4=2\left[{tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right)}\right]$$

and hit enter and was shown  $Done$ on the screen. However when I typed in $\theta4$ and hit enter, it seems as though it only calculated the equation using the variable $b$. It gave me the output:

$$0.620709\cdot tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{-4\cdot (ac-0.5)}+1.41421\right)$$

It is worth noting when I actually substitute both $a$ and $c$ into the equation at this point I am shown $Error: \space Domain\space error$

So my question is, how to I get my equation to include all of the variables defined within it, and then why I am I getting a domain error? Thank you

Comment: My guess is that the evaluation involves taking the square root of a negative number.  You should do some reading of the manual to make sure $ac$ is treated as a product.  It would seem likely that a calculator would require $a*c$ instead.

Comment: Yep, it seems that what was wrong. It was interpreting ac as it's own variable and my b value was too small, hence resulting in a square root of a negative. Thanks for you help.

Comment: One more question, do you know how to save variables with subscripts in the calculator? I am trying to save different angles as variables i.e. $\theta_2$ etc

Comment: Sorry, I don't happen to know that.  Questions about how the calculator works (as opposed to how to accomplish a mathematical task using math software) are off-topic here.  I would search on the Internet (if you don't have the manual) for "TI Nspire user variables".  It seems there are two versions of the calculator, a CAS and a non-CAS, and you would be more knowledgeable than I which kind you have.  Math.SE doesn't do software support questions.